# Rendering highcharts to custom svg?

Tags: svg, highcharts

Is this possible to render highcharts to custom svg container?
I need to push few charts to single svg element.
I know I could use .getSvg(), but I need to be able to update data on the chart later, without redrawing the whole chart.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately it is not suppored, highcharts renders the chart in additional divs and adds elements like labels/datalabels as html objects.

Using getSVG() allows to generate a copy of chart without any events/

You can try to use jQuery.clone() on $('#container svg').